# Why does WP auto-complete the a-tag?

Tags: wordpress, post, anchor

If I write a post or a page containitg:

`<a href="#something"> bla </a>`

WP autocompletes it with

`<a href="http://www.thewholedamnpath.com/?page_id=291#something">bla</a>`

I sincerely don't need this feature,
so, what is the way to bypass it?

Comment: Why would you want to fight this functionality? Sure, it's not necessary, but no modern browser will be even slightly hindered by it.

Comment: i wanna implement this nice toy to my theme: http://css-tricks.com/examples/OrganicTabs/
it simply doesn't work if WP changes the href attribute

Comment: Are you sure that is WP function? Isn't it browser's rendered url? To check this out go to View-> Source code and search for #something

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/raw-html/

Using the plugin a chunk of code can be wrapped inside [RAW]...[/RAW] tags, and that code will remain **untouched** by WordPress.